# Converting Canvas to Pdf using JsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, html5-canvas, jspdf

I am trying to convert canvas into pdf but i get clean white pdf in result
Here is the code, I am not being able to figure out what i am missing..

```
function HtmlToImage(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var img =canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");  
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    pdf.output('datauri');
                }
          });
       }
```

Comment: lol your question was my answer.  Doing what you did there correctly added the image for me

Comment: @owengerig: Glad to know my post helped you  :)

Comment: Me too! Here is the refactor of your code: `html2canvas(document.getElementById('comprobante'), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var img =canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
                    var pdf = new jsPDF();
                    pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
                    pdf.output('datauri');
                    pdf.save('autoprint.pdf');
                }
            });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    pdf.output('datauri');
});
```

See http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Comment: it says ..pdf.addHTML(document.body,function()

Comment: sorry, means debugger is not recognizing this addHTML function

Comment: addHTML is a new jsPDF plugin, pick the latest version from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/dist

Comment: blurry image found using this sadly

Answer (score 0):

> function canvas2pdf(){
> var img =canvas.toDataURL();
> var pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF();
> pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
> pdf.save('canvas.pdf');
> }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).